# How to create live streaming for multiple social media like Facebook, Youtube using RTMP in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, rtmp, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have done live streaming for a single platform like facebook using LFLivekit. When I am trying for two platforms it's not happening.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import LFLiveKit

class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

var sessionO: LFLiveSession =
    {
        let audioConfiguration = LFLiveAudioConfiguration.defaultConfiguration(for: LFLiveAudioQuality.high)
        let videoConfiguration = LFLiveVideoConfiguration.defaultConfiguration(for: LFLiveVideoQuality.low3)
        let session = LFLiveSession(audioConfiguration: audioConfiguration, videoConfiguration: videoConfiguration)
        return session!
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.streamUrl = "live-api-s.facebook.com:80/rtmp/"
        self.streamName = "17XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

        self.sessionO.delegate = self
        self.sessionO.preView = self.view
        self.sessionO.running = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let stream = LFLiveStreamInfo()
        stream.url = "rtmp://\(self.streamUrl!)/LiveApp/\(self.streamName!)"
        self.sessionO.startLive(stream)
}
}
```

Note: If I create one more session and stream also for youtube it is not working.

Comment: do you want simultaneously streaming on facebook and you-tube?

Comment: Yes I want that.

Answer (score 0):

We need to create separate RTMP connection and create the listener.

```
fbRtmpStream = RTMPStream(connection: fbRtmpConnection)
ytRtmpStream = RTMPStream(connection: ytRtmpConnection)

self.fbRtmpConnection1.addEventListener(Event.RTMP_STATUS, selector:#selector(self.fbRtmpStatusHandler1(_:)), observer: self)
        self.fbRtmpConnection1.connect("rtmp://live-api-s.facebook.com:80/rtmp/")
        self.fbStreamName1 = "xxxxxx"

self.ytRtmpConnection.addEventListener(Event.RTMP_STATUS, selector:#selector(self.ytRtmpStatusHandler(_:)), observer: self)
        self.ytRtmpConnection.connect("rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/LiveApp/")
        self.ytStreamName = "xxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution you're looking for [source](https://github.com/LaiFengiOS/LFLiveKit/issues/200)

Multiple server upload main problem is the error handling more complex, for example, the way out of the problem，this has not yet been good how to deal with. [source](https://github.com/LaiFengiOS/LFLiveKit/issues/10#issuecomment-239057402)

So! LFLiveKit **does not support** multiple server